# "table or view does not exist", but only sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-connection, oledb

A SQL select statement gets run when a user presses a button on my website, and I do this:

```
connection = new OleDbConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = [connection string];
connection.Open();

cmd = profile.Execute(mySQLStatement);
da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
table = new DataTable();
da.Fill(table);
```

90% of the time, this works just fine. But every once in a while, I get the OleDbException `table or view does not exist` on the line `da.Fill(table)`. There doesn't seem to be a pattern of when this works and when it doesn't, though it's more likely to not work when the site isn't used for a minute or two... Like the session might be expiring. But the rest of the website (that does not require this database) works.

Any ideas of what might be happening or how to fix it?

Comment: It might have something to do with how you are building `mySQLStatment`, so you might want to put up your code for that.

Comment: Showing us the code for `OpenDatabaseConnection` would also be helpful.

Comment: `mySqlStatement` is the same string in the same use case in both working and not working situations. Also I added some more relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a solution. As a temporary fix, whenever this happens, I just re-start the page.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the content of mySqlStatement is not exactly correct, maybe? 
Trap the exception dump mySqlStatement to a logfile (with date and time this happened), and then throw.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but no, `mySqlStatement` is as expected.

Comment: So you have a log already? Is it always the same table/ view? There has to be a common factor and once the obvious out the way, no way we can do anything more than guess. Chances of one of us guessing right are a significantly less than slim.

Comment: What about connection string? Does it always point to the same DB where table/view exists?